# How to combine or automatically compiler different programe such as python3 , R( 3.5.6 ) and sageMath 8.3

Tags: bash, python3, make, r, sagemath

I have three file written on different program such as

1. `file1.py`
2. `file2.sage`
3. `file3.r`

I will give input then I want to work the following steps automatically

- `file1.py` read and after progress it will give `output1.txt`
- `file2.sage` read `output1.txt and` after progress it will give `output2.txt`
- `file3.r` read `output2.txt` and after progress it will give `output3.txt`

I tried bash programming as the following

```
!# /usr/bash/

python3 file1.py

sage file2.sage

r file3.r
```

and then I done the bash program run as program via

- `chmod +x bashprogram`
- `./bashprogram`

It doesn't work. I have not used **make** function on ubuntu. Maybe it will help me but I dont know how can do that.

Comment: The first line in your bash script should probably be `#!/bin/bash`. I don't see any "compiling" in your question. Do the three scripts work as expected when you run them one after the other in a terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I overcame about it by using your answer which  `#!/bin/bash`.